# AWS: Application vs Classic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balance

My senario is this:

I am using 2 EC2 instances which I want reachable via urls as follows:

```
sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.com
```

I am aware of the fact that AWS Application Load Balancers currently support [host based routing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) so I guess this is now feasible.

Currently I am using 2 **Classic** Load Balancers on AWS to support access to those instances;

Is there a reason for me to switch to the host-based routing scenario of ALBs?

Perhaps the motive for this question is silly, but lately Amazon in its console, has grayed out the Classic ELB and marked it as

> Previous Generation

(I guess this wouldn't be a strong motive but it kind of discourages you a bit from using Classic ELBs henceforth...)

P.S. Haven't got the chance to test it, but I assume if I have issued an AWS wildcard certificate for `*.domain.com`, this would cover all target groups (i.e. hosts) under the ALB, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) you are using **2** classic ELBs instead of **1** ALB
so costs savings can be a factor

2) using a layer7 loadbalancer vs a layer4 gives many features and capabilities not possible otherwise

you can see a comparrison here: 
https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#compare

3) yes that wildcard would fit all your needs (sub1/sub2.domain.com)